# CSS 3 Animation - Sliding Across Screen

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have this: http://d.pr/i/A2b3 which acts as the divider between the header and the main content.

The image is set as the background image, repeat-x, of the header container.

```
<header> <--- image is background of this
    <div id="container"></div>
</header>
```

I want the image to slide across the screen slowly almost in a wave like effect. Is this possible with CCS3 animations? If so can someone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using jQuery and a simple image slider with a shortened image pause so the image keeps on switching. As far as i know its not possible to get a video to appear in a slider (not without a play button of some sort). http://www.catchmyfame.com/2009/06/04/jquery-infinite-carousel-plugin/ would be an example of what i would use.

Comment: If you change : displayTime : 10000, to displayTime : 1, (for example) that keeps on switching the images. (just add the same image twice)

Comment: Think you might be missing the point. I don't want a slider. It's one image which is repeated across the width of the screen. However rather than it being static I want it to appear to be moving across the page. A bit like this: http://jsfiddle.net/peterbenoit/npcaH/ but moving right to left as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

CSS:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background-image: url(http://www.scottishheritageusa.org/imgs/header_separator.png); //replace with your image
    background-position: 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    -webkit-animation: myanim 5s infinite linear;
       -moz-animation: myanim 5s infinite linear;
         -o-animation: myanim 5s infinite linear;
            animation: myanim 5s infinite linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myanim {
    0%   { background-position: 0px; }
    100% { background-position: 100px; } /* set this to the width of the image */
}
@-moz-keyframes myanim {
    0%   { background-position: 0px; }
    100% { background-position: 100px; } /* set this to the width of the image */
}
@-o-keyframes myanim {
    0%   { background-position: 0px; }
    100% { background-position: 100px; } /* set this to the width of the image */
}
@keyframes myanim {
    0%   { background-position: 0px; }
    100% { background-position: 100px; } /* set this to the width of the image */
}
```

I created a Fiddle for you to play with here:
http://jsfiddle.net/e3WLD/3/